# White Screen on Page load - Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Consistently when I open this website http://celsowhite.com/IM/ in Google Chrome the first load shows a white screen.

Immediately when I re-size the browser or open the developer tools it appears. It also appears if I refresh the window.

I'm not sure what is causing this. Originally I thought it was the js/froogaloop.min.js which I use to load the JavaScript video.

This issue only appears in Chrome.

Comment: What do you see when you debug using something like [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)?

Comment: Loads OK for me in Chrome Version 33.0.1750.146 for OSX 10.9.1

Comment: No problems on Win with 33.0.1750.146 m.

Comment: good to know it is working for others. I'll keep testing and try it in fiddler. I'm noticing that clicking the link opens the site. When I type it into the chrome browser the above issue occurs.

Comment: @88MPG Can you try and paste the link into a new browser tab/window then access the page? Rather than clicking the link from above. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @howderek where you able to fix this issue ? has it happened to you on mac ? I have the same problem

Comment: @happyOasis I just edited the question, Celso was the person who asked it and I'm not sure if they fixed it or not :/ sorry

Comment: @happyOasis this happened to fix itself. This was likely a bug on my local computer because it seemed to work fine with others.